# React-Router not correctly rendering Styled-Components Styles

Tags: reactjs, react-router, styled-components

The issue is that when I navigate to a 'Post', expanded screen, then use my browser to go back, it is not showing the correct CSS styles, it is using the styles from the expanded view, rather than the 'non-expanded' view. If I toggle a style on the Component using Inspect Element it fixes the issue immediately. I know I could probably circumvent this by adding a back button on the page, and I probably will, but what about the people who use the browser back button?

I am trying to use the same StyledComponent for different pages. Here is the code for my router

```
<Router>
      <Route
        exact
        path="/"
        render={() => posts.map((post, key) => <Post data={post} key={key} />)}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path={`/posts/:post`}
        render={currentPath => renderCurrentPost(currentPath)}
      />
    </Router>
```

All that the second route does is find the correct post to render, then render it.

Here is my code for the specific styled component.

```
import Styled from 'styled-components';
const Title = Styled.h1`
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap');
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-style: medium;
    color: ${props => (props.expanded ? `white` : `#111111`)}
    font-size: ${props => (props.expanded ? `5vh` : `1.2em`)}
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    align-self: flex-end;
    /* display: inline; */
    position: ${props => (props.expanded ? `relative` : ``)};
    top: ${props => (props.expanded ? `70%` : ``)};    
    left: ${props => (props.expanded ? `5%` : ``)};
     `;

export default Title;
```

I am using props heavily in these components as it will change the way it renders.

Here is the desired style that renders correctly when you first navigate to the landing page.[image: Desired Style]

Here is the non-desired styling that happens when you navigate back from a expanded post page using the browser back button.[image: Non-Desire Style]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered this myself by slowly removing each CSS line from my styled component to find the problem, which turned out to be this line of code

```
padding: ${props => (props.expanded ? `` : `0 2% 0 10%`)};
```